# Concurrently retrieve or create new row using JDBI SQL Object API

Tags: mysql, jdbi

I'm using JDBI and would like to use the [SQL Object API](http://jdbi.org/sql_object_overview/) in order to, given a field value, search if a row exists for this value, return its key if found, create it if not found and return the generated key (talking to a MySQL database).

Is it possible to do this using SQL Object API without any stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no magic in the JDBI SQL Object API whch will do this for you. You will need several SQL statements, just as you would in a stored procedure.

If you want to combine it in a single method in your DAO class, you can make it an abstract class rather than an interface, then it can have a concrete method containing the logic you need, and annotate that to make it occur within a transaction:

```
  public abstract class MyDAO {

    @Transaction
    public long getId(String value) {
      Thing thing = findByValue(value);
      if (thing != null) {
        return thing.getId();
      } else {
        return addNewRecord(value);
      } 

    }

    @SqlQuery("select * from mytable where value = :value")
    public Thing findByValue(@Bind("value") String value);

    @SqlUpdate("insert into mytable (value) values (:value)")
    @GetGeneratedKeys
    public long addNewRecord(String value);

  }
```

Comment: This approach is not safe: two concurrent clients (perhaps running on separate machines) can both fail to find the record, then both insert a new record, resulting in a duplicate. You can prevent the duplicate using a database constraint (primary key or unique index), but that will result in one of the clients failing with an exception.

Comment: Not necessarily, all depends on the [transaction isolation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) you chose for your `Connection`, am I wrong?

Comment: Mmh I think you're right, even with a transaction isolation set to `TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE` the field containing the value must be `UNIQUE` in order to prevent duplicates...

Answer (score 1):

To do this correctly, you need to handle the concurrency inside the database. Create the table where `value` is a unique index:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id bigint NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  value varchar(100) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

You can then use MySQL's `INSERT IGNORE` syntax, which skips errors such as duplicate keys:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mytable VALUES (:value);
```

After the insert, read the row:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE value = :value;
```

If always running the extra insert is a performance concern, you can perform the read first and only insert if the record does not exist.